# Find $\epsilon$ of a finite size $\epsilon$-net of a $d$-dimensional unit ball$

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry, packing-problem

I have a set of $d$-dimensional vectors $V = \{+1, 0, -1\}^d $. Then $P(V)$ constitutes the power set of $V$. I now construct a set of unit vectors $V_{sum}$ from the power set $P(V)$ such that
$$
V_{sum} = \left\{\frac{\bar{v}}{\|\bar{v}\|} \quad \Bigg|  \quad  \exists S \in P(V),\quad  \bar{v} =\sum_{v \in S} v \right\}
$$ 
That is, each subset $S \in P(V)$ contributes to a vector in $V_{sum}$ formed as a sum of all the vectors in the subset $S$ and then taking the unit vector in that direction.

Note that there could be duplicates. For example, for $d = 3$, the vector $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ can be formed as a sum of vectors of any of the following subsets $$S_1 = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\},\\ S_2 = \{(1,1,0
),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\},\\ S_3 = \{(1,1,1)\}.$$

and many more possibilities.

Now I want to find the maximum of Euclidean distance between any vector in $V_{sum}$ to its closest vector in $V_{sum}$. Is there an easy way to upper bound this max distance? (Ignoring the zero vector in $V_{sum}$).

In other words, if I consider $V_{sum}$ to be an $\epsilon$-net to the surface of the unit ball in $d$-dimensions, then I want to find an upper bound on $\epsilon$. Any weak upper bound on $\epsilon$ should suffice. The goal is to show that $V_{sum}$ forms a better $\epsilon$-net than the unit vectors formed from the vectors in $V$.

Comment: Your definition of $V_{sum}$ doesn't make sense. Do you actually mean $$V_{sum} = \left\{\dfrac{\bar v}{\|\bar v\|} \, \middle | \,\bar v = \sum_{v\in S} v, S\in P(V)\right\}?$$ Otherwise, you need to explain how you are summing $v$ when the $v$ are not vectors but sets of vectors, and how a single $\bar v$ could be equal to every such sum at the same time.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, yes, that was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: What do you do in the case $v = 0$? Which vector do you choose then on the unit ball?

Comment: @Targon, since I am interested in showing that $V_{sum}$ forms an $\varepsilon$-net of the "surface" of the unit ball in $d$-dimensions, I need not consider the vector $v = 0$ in $V_{sum}$. So, I can ignore this case.

Comment: You fixed only one of the two things I pointed out. Your $V_{sum}$ is currently empty, because it is impossible for a single $\bar v$ to be equal to $\sum_{v\in S} v$ for *every* set $S$. Since there are sets $S$ with different sums, "$\forall S$" cannot be satisfied. You need either "$\exists S \in P(V), \bar v = \sum_{v\in S} v$" or else the unquantified version I gave. ("$\exists S$" is arguably the better version, but the notation supports either form. But your version means something different than you obviously intended.)

Comment: Also, there is no reason to bring in $P(V)$ at all. "$S \in P(V)$" means exactly the same thing as "$S \subseteq V$", so you could just phrase it that way. But this is a matter of style, whereas the other is a mistaken notation.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, yes you are right. Its fixed now.

Comment: One other correction: $\bar v$ can be $0$ - for example, it is for $S = V$ - so you can't always divide by its norm. I'm guessing you want to exclude this case, so you should add "$\bar v \ne 0$" to your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer. Since I find myself being too distracted by other things to push it any further, I decided to put out what I've come up with so far in hopes it might help.

Since the set consists of unital vectors, the inner products are the cosines of the angles between them. So the smaller the distance between any two vectors, the larger the inner product. So the find the closest neighbor to a vector, one must look for the other vector that maximizes the inner product with it. This maximum is necessarily $< 1$. If we didn't need distinct vectors, the maximum would be $1$, the inner product of a vector $v$ with itself. For distinct vectors, the inner product is maximized for vectors with coordinates as near to those of $v$ as possible. But to maintain a norm of $1$, if some coordinate decreases from that of $v$, there must be some other coordinate that increases. I have not yet investigated whether you can get closer by concentrating these changes in as few coordinates as possible, or spreading them out over as many coordinates as possible, but surely one or the other approach will give the closest other point.

Then to find the maximum distance between two closest neighbors, you need to look for vectors for which the changes between neighbors are necessarily as big as possible. This will occur when the coordinates of your first point are as low as possible. I suspect (but again, have not confirmed) that vectors with a single non-zero coordinate will have the farthest neighbors. The reason is the relative change from $0$ to $1$ is bigger than the relative change from $d$ to $d + 1$ for larger $d$.